# Error in loading variables from GUI to workspace in Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have created a GUI in Matlab and made a simple pushbutton function in GUI for running my matlab file.

```
function pushbutton7_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % hObject    handle to pushbutton7 (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
Uncertainty_MMS_refactored_Final;
```

I can load my text files (e.g. PTX_Data_Raw.txt) via GUI in workspace by using **assignin** function.

```
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
[filename_2,PathName]=uigetfile({'*.txt'},'Import Reference PTX file without header');
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
PTX_Raw = importdata(filename_2);
assignin('base', 'PTX_Data_Raw', PTX_Raw);
content = filename_2; 
set(handles.edit2, 'string', content,'fontsize',12);
```

But when I run my code  via GUI byy pusshing "push button" button  I receive this error:

Undefined function or variable 'PTX_Data_Raw'

while I check my workspace, I can see all files that I have loaded from GUI to workspace and even I can run my program with F5 button via keyboard! but I don't know why I can run my code via GUI?! HERE is the code that I have written for running my matlab file. here is the full error that I receive:
Undefined function or variable 'PTX_file'.

Error in Uncertainty_MMS_refactored_Final (line 21)
RefOrgnizedData = OrgnizingData(PTX_file, PTX_Data_Raw);

Undefined function or variable 'PTX_file'.

Error in GUI>pushbutton7_Callback (line 178)
Uncertainty_MMS_refactored_Final;

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in GUI (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in @(hObject,eventdata)GUI('pushbutton7_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))

Error using waitfor
Error while evaluating UIControl Callback

Should I change or add something else more? please help me

Comment: By any chance do you run your GUI through the GUIDE environment? If so this is wrong. Moreover, this piece of code does not help us at all to diagnose the problem. Please put a minimum example that reproduces the error. Thanks!

Comment: @Benoit_11, Hi Benoit. I updated my question. please let me know if you have any idea

Comment: Are you sure it's this callback that is throwing the error? Please post the full error message and stack trace.

Comment: @excaza, I updated my post.

Comment: Based on the error message your issue is unrelated to any of the provided code. `Uncertainty_MMS_refactored_Final` is attempting to pass `PTX_file` to `OrganizingData` but `PTX_file` is not defined. Please read the error message and provide the appropriate code.

Comment: I would also take a look at MATLAB's documentation, [functions run in their own workspace](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/base-and-function-workspaces.html) so data you are loading into the base MATLAB workspace with `evalin` are not going to be accessible to other functions in your GUI. See [Share Data Among Callbacks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html) for more appropriate methodologies.